# Snackbar slide transition not working in mui 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am migrating from material-ui 4 to mui 5 and Whenever I want my snackbar to appear, it is giving me this error in the console.

[image]

I figured out It had something to do with the `Slide` component that I have passed to my snackbar as a `TransitionComponent`.

Here's the code.

```
import React from 'react';

import Slide from '@mui/material/Slide';
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import withStyles from '@mui/styles/withStyles';

import Alert from 'containers/Alert';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    minWidth: '37rem',
    maxWidth: '55rem',
    height: theme.spacing(6),
  },
});

const SlideTransition = (props) => {
  return (<Slide {...props}
    direction='up' />);
};

/**
 * @param {props} props all the props for the component
 * @return {Button}
 */
const CustomSnackbar = (props) => {
  const {
    classes,
    handleClose,
    handleUndo,
    horizontal = 'right',
    open,
    text,
    severity,
    style,
    vertical = 'bottom',
  } = props;
  return (<Snackbar
    anchorOrigin={{horizontal, vertical}}
    autoHideDuration={3000}
    onClose={handleClose}
    open={open}
    TransitionComponent={SlideTransition}
  >
    <Alert
      handleClose={handleClose}
      handleUndo={handleUndo}
      open={open}
      severity={severity}
      styleClass={`${classes.root} ${style}`}
      text={text}
    />
  </Snackbar>);
};

CustomSnackbar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object,
  handleClose: PropTypes.func,
  handleUndo: PropTypes.func,
  horizontal: PropTypes.string,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  severity: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  style: PropTypes.string,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  vertical: PropTypes.string,
};

export default (withStyles(useStyles)(CustomSnackbar));
```

In mui 5 documentation for Snackbar I have seen this codesandbox, where I tested it out and somehow it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/directionsnackbar-material-demo-forked-1jshr?file=/demo.js

I want to know what I am doing wrong!?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap `Slide` with `TransitionSlide`, use this instead:

```
...
TransitionComponent={Slide}
anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "bottom" }}
```

The toast will pop up from the bottom right corner.

Also, I would like to share my experience of using Snackckbar, it can be useful for someone else. I encountered similar errors when I placed the variable that returned JSX. I created that variable for customizing purpose.

```
<Snackbar
  open={isOpen}
  autoHideDuration={DEFAULT_AUTO_HIDE_DURATION}
  onClose={clearNotification}
  TransitionComponent={Slide}
  anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "top" }}
>
  {alert} // errors
  <Alert ... /> // no errors
</Snackbar>
```

To fix it I created separate Snackbars with appropriate styled Alert.

So, if you want to override default "TransitionComponent" and avoid warnings/errors in the browser console, you need properly pass `children` for `Snackbar`.